# Binding/Injecting a Scala function (not whole class) using Guice?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice

I'd like to inject the `byId` method of my `UserDao` object into the constructor of my `Authentication` object. I want to avoid injecting the whole class.

```
// Has def byId(id: UserId): Option[User]
bind(classOf[UserDao]).asEagerSingleton()

// Something like this
bindMethod(classOf[UserDao], _.byId)

// Constructor takes a (UserId) => Option[User] function
bind(classOf[Authentication]).asEagerSingleton()
```

I'm using Guice with the Play Framework. Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to ask this as it can greatly simplify testing. The trick is to use the [@Provides](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods#provides-methods) annotation:

## TL;DR

```
class MyController @Inject() (byId: (UserId) => Option[User]) extends Controller { ... }

@Provides
def userDao(aDependency: Any): UserDao = // return UserDao, note aDependency will be injected

@Provides
def byId: (UserId) => Option[User] = userDao.byId // note: this method will call the other @Provides method 'userDao'
```

## Explanation

Ultimately `byId: (UserId) => Option[User]` translates to `scala.Function1[UserId, Option[User]]` however you can declare function dependencies using the syntactic sugar:

```
class MyController @Inject() (_addTwo: (Int, Int) => Int) extends Controller {

  def addTwo(a: Int, b: Int) = Action {
    Ok(_addTwo(a, b).toString) // call the injected function 
  }

}
```

Then in your Module.scala create a method which returns the function:

```
@Provides
def addTwo: (Int, Int) => Int = (a, b) => a + b
```

You can do all the usual Scala stuff in the @Provides method, e.g. returning a partially applied function:

```
@Provides
def addTwo: (Int, Int) => Int = addThree(0, _:Int, _:Int)

def addThree(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): Int = a + b + c
```

To avoid conflicts you can also use the [@Named](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#named) annotation:

```
class MyController @Inject() (@Named("addTwo") _addTwo: (Int, Int) => Int, 
                              @Named("subtractTwo") _subTwo: (Int, Int) => Int) 
                              extends Controller { ... }

@Provides
@Named("addTwo")
def addTwo: (Int, Int) => Int = (a, b) => a + b

@Provides
@Named("subtractTwo")
def subTwo: (Int, Int) => Int = (a, b) => a - b
```

Comment: How does the `def byId: (User) => Option[User]` compile? My code asks my to provide the argument `aDependency` when I call `userDao`. Without that argument, I cannot use `byId`. Is there a way to automagically capture all dependencies from Guice without writing an @Provides for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, what you want is encapsulation ?

If so, I suggest to use a code like this :

```
// User model
case class User(id: UUID, name: String)

trait AuthenticationUserDao{
  def findById: Option[User]
}

class UserDao extends AuthenticationUserDao {
  override def findById: Option[User] = ???
  def add(user: User): Boolean = ???
  def delete(userId: UUID): Boolean = ???
}

// ...

class Authentication @Inject() (
                                 authenticationUserDao: AuthenticationUserDao
                               ) extends Controller {

  // Here only the method findById is available (not tested, but i guest it's the case here)

  def findUser(userId: UUID) = Action {
    authenticationUserDao.findById(userId)
  }

}

// ...

bind(classOf[UserDao]).to(classOf[AuthenticationUserDao])
```

Hope I have well understood.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I only want to pass in a single function to my Authentication class. Not a whole class, or trait. The nice thing about Scala and Java 8 is being able to pass simple lambdas as dependencies between classes, which is far cleaner, and more testable, than passing whole classes or traits.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you for the explanation.